# Use props inside method in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

I have props like below

```
props: ['applicants',],
```

I would like to use `props` like below

```
  methods : {
            formated (item) {
                var _self = this;                
                _self.values.length = 0;
                if(item == "") {
                   console.log(this.applicants); //I am getting output here
                   _self.values = this.applicants 
                }
                else {
                  console.log(this.applicants);  //I am not getting output here
                  this.applicants.filter(applicant => { }) 
                }
            }
   }
```

Why it is happening like this?

Comment: Did you mean to do this? `_self.values = this.applicants.filter(applicant => { })` The filter function doesn't edit the array, it returns a new one.

Comment: Also, there's no need for `var _self = this` at the top. Access `this` directly, as long as the functions inside of here are arrow functions.

Comment: Thanks @kingdaro. I edited the question. I think that is helpful for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a reference to `this`. Assuming `this.values` is an array:

```
methods: {
  formatted (item) {
    this.values = item == "" ? this.applicants : this.applicants.filter(applicant => { })
  }
}
```